# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined on Anonymous function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This code works fine.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',(function(){
        console.log("test");
    }));
```

However I want to pass the variable to function, but it show the error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',(function(show){
        console.log(show);
    })("test"));
```

Where is wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an [immediate anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) in callback. Below code is immediately executed when the browser encounters it:

```js
(function(show){
    console.log(show);
})("test")
```

and return `undefined` which is not a function. Hence the error. Try something as below:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',handleClick);

function handleClick(){
    callback('show');
}

function callback(val){
    console.log(val);
}
```

Comment: I change 'show' in handleClick() to variable and it works. Thank you very much.